# No Django como restringir alteração de apenas um field do model após ter inserido um valor?

Tags: python, django

Exemplo.:

```
class Cadastro(models.Model):

    class Tipos(models.TextChoices):
        PERFIL_A = 'perfil B', 'Perfil A'
        PERFIL_B = 'perfil B', 'Perfil B'

    id = models.UUIDField(primary_key=True, editable=False, default=uuid.uuid4)
    nome = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tipo_perfil = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=Tipos.choices)'
```

o field 'tipo_perfil' não quero que altere após ter escolhido, é possível?
Tem algum recurso do django ou precisaria fazer uma logica no model?

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que você esteja montando um formulário para o usuário. Sendo assim, você pode fazer isso no `forms.py`

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
class CadastroUpdateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Cadastro
        fields = ['nome', 'tipo_perfil']
        labels = {
            'nome': 'Nome',
            'tipo_perfil': 'Perfil',
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['tipo_perfil'].disabled = True
```

Veja que no `__init__` o campo `tipo_perfil` está desabilitado pela linha:

> self.fields['tipo_perfil'].disabled = True

Embora esteja *hardcoded* no exemplo, você pode passar como parâmetro na inicialização desta classe.

Comment: Obrigado, meu ajudou muito